# Enable the Site Editor on my old own custom theme for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, templates, editor

I created a custom theme some years ago and I want to activate the Site Editor icon and use the Templates editor. I added this:

```
function mon_theme_support_editor_de_site() {
    add_theme_support( 'wp-block-styles' );
    add_theme_support( 'block-templates' );
    add_theme_support( 'responsive-embeds' );
    add_theme_support( 'align-wide' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mon_theme_support_editor_de_site' );
```

in my functions.php but nothing appears in the back-office of my Wordpress.

What do I have to change or do?

Comment: I found a solution, you have to add a templates folder and within this folder add index.html (templates/index.html) and then the "Customizer" button in the back-office changed to "Editor" :-)

Comment: Please post that as an answer instead of a comment.